# How to aggregate sum in MongoDB to get a total count?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

For some collection with a field `{ wins: Number }`, how could I use *MongoDB Aggregation Framework* to get the total number of wins across all documents in a collection?

#### Example:

If I have 3 documents with `wins: 5`, `wins: 8`, `wins: 12` respectively, how could I use MongoDB Aggregation Framework to return the total number, i.e. `total: 25`.

Comment: Use a `$group` operation as shown in [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#stage._S_group).

Comment: @JohnnyHK I've tried `db.characters.aggregate([{$group:{_id:'id',wins:{$sum:1}}}]);` but without any luck. It returns how many `wins` fields i have instead of values from the wins.

Comment: `db.characters.aggregate( [
   { $group: { _id: null,
               total: { $sum: "$wins" } } }
] )`

Comment: @WiredPrairie Thank you it worked. Do you want to post it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

### Sum

To get the sum of a grouped field when using the Aggregation Framework of MongoDB, you'll need to use `$group` and `$sum`:

```
db.characters.aggregate([ { 
    $group: { 
        _id: null, 
        total: { 
            $sum: "$wins" 
        } 
    } 
} ] )
```

In this case, if you want to get the sum of all of the `wins`, you need to refer to the field name using the `$` syntax as `$wins` which just fetches the values of the `wins` field from the grouped documents and sums them together.

### Count

You can `sum` other values as well by passing in a specific value (as you'd done in your comment). If you had

`{ "$sum" : 1 }`,

that would actually be a count of all of the `wins`, rather than a total.

Comment: What would you do if this query takes a long time? (runs across many documents)

Comment: As this algorithm must scan every document, you'll need to resort to caching, precalculation, or filtering the results to reduce the overall time spent.

Comment: How do you get the result? I get a cursor back.

Comment: Why do you need the `[ ]` ? It works without them, i.e. `db.characters.aggregate({$group ... })` instead of `db.characters.aggregate([{$group ... }])` .

Comment: In this case it works because the pipeline only has one stage, but I think most of the times you use it you'll have more (stages) https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline

Comment: Wow, `_id: null`  is the key here. +1 you tried to use the aggregation framework without thinking about using `_id: null`.