# Count struct slice length in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB with Golang.

I have the following struct which my query result will write to:

```
var slacks []struct {
        Name        string `json:"name"`
        Description string `json:"description"`
        PostCount   int    `json:"postCount"`
    } `json:"slacks"`
}
```

I have documents in my collection which look like:

```
type slack struct {
    ID          bson.ObjectId   `bson:"_id"`
    Name        string          `bson:"name"`
    Description string          `bson:"description"`
    Posts       []post          `bson:"posts"`
}
```

My aim is to count the posts in each slack using a MongoDB query.
I've got this so far:

```
db.C("slacks").Find(&bson.M{"name": &bson.RegEx{
    Pattern: ".*" + searchStr + ".*",
    Options: "i",
}}).Select(&bson.M{
    "name":        1,
    "description": 1,
    "$size":       "posts",
}).All(&slacks)
```

But `{"$size": "posts"}` doesn't do the trick.

How can I query the length of an array/slice of struct in a MongoDB query in Golang?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has nothing to do with Go. It's just about how to form a MongoDB query.

Comment: I'm trying to complete this task from my Golang program. I added Go just so the answer will help me... thanks for the suggestion though (and the edit...)

Comment: Sure, you're using it in Go, but once you have a working query, you can use it in any language.

Comment: I'm happy with how my question is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to aggregate sum in MongoDB to get a total count?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044587/how-to-aggregate-sum-in-mongodb-to-get-a-total-count)

Comment: Have you tried `$count` instead of `$size`?

Comment: I've tried these things... the only issue is that `PostCount int \`json:"postCount"\`` might not be actually the field catching the result of the post count.

What would the `"$size": "posts"` 's field name be?

Comment: Flimzy, can you just  leave my post alone, I'm not trying to sum numbers in an array...

Comment: [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) is an `aggregate` operator; you can't use it with `find`.

Comment: Ok thank you. Would you recommend I select all the posts and count them in my program, or store a new key such as `postCount`?

Comment: No, use an [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) for your query instead of `Find`. Your question appears to be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722850/querying-internal-array-size-in-mongodb