# Mongo aggregation - sum multiple items in dictionary in single call

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have precomputed statistics for every organisation document inside simple dictionary like this:

```
"stats": {
    "draft" : 15,
    "published" : 12,
    "scheduled" : 0,
    "archived" : 2,
    "removed" : 3
}
```

Now I need overall stats for all organisations (group all organisations), so the result should look the same, just the numbers will be sum of all respective fields (`drafts` will contain sum of all `drafts` in all organisations).

Is that possible to do in single aggregate call?

(I know all possible keys in `stats` dictionary if that helps.)

Comment: Something like `db.colname.aggregate([
      {"$group":{
        "_id":"all",
        "draft":{"$sum":"$stats.draft"},
        ...list other stats fields...
      }}
    ])`

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044587/how-to-aggregate-sum-in-mongodb-to-get-a-total-count